# Parsing HTML data from Wunderground

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

All,

I am trying to download the weather data history from Wunderground. The problem that I have is that I need the full METAR information.

Here is the example that I want to download: [CSV with full METAR](http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/KBUF/2011/1/1/DailyHistory.html?theprefset=SHOWMETAR&theprefvalue=1&format=1).

Since I want to download the hourly data for the whole year, I need to script them. But no matter what I tried (bash with wget, or python), I still cannot have the page with full METAR via the script.

Here is the example of my script:

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
url = "http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/KBUF/2011/1/1/DailyHistory.html?theprefset=SHOWMETAR&theprefvalue=1&format=1"
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
dailyData = page.read()                            
print dailyData
```

What I have is something like:

```
12:54 AM,52.0,45.0,77,29.93,10.0,SSW,15.0,-,N/A,,Scattered Clouds,200,2011-01-01 05:54:00<br />
1:54 AM,53.1,45.0,74,29.95,10.0,SSW,12.7,-,N/A,,Mostly Cloudy,200,2011-01-01 06:54:00<br />
2:54 AM,50.0,44.1,80,29.95,10.0,SSW,8.1,-,N/A,,Mostly Cloudy,200,2011-01-01 07:54:00<br />
3:54 AM,51.1,44.1,77,29.93,10.0,SSE,5.8,-,N/A,,Scattered Clouds,150,2011-01-01 08:54:00<br />
```

Through a web browswer, this is what I get - note a new column that starts with METAR:

```
12:54 AM,52.0,45.0,77,29.93,10.0,SSW,15.0,-,N/A,,Scattered Clouds,METAR KBUF 010554Z COR 20013KT 10SM FEW045 SCT140 11/07 A2992 RMK AO2 SLP134 60004 T01110072 10111 20078 58016,200,2011-01-01 05:54:00
1:54 AM,53.1,45.0,74,29.95,10.0,SSW,12.7,-,N/A,,Mostly Cloudy,METAR KBUF 010654Z 20011KT 10SM BKN055 BKN130 12/07 A2994 RMK AO2 SLP141 T01170072,200,2011-01-01 06:54:00
2:54 AM,50.0,44.1,80,29.95,10.0,SSW,8.1,-,N/A,,Mostly Cloudy,METAR KBUF 010754Z 20007KT 10SM BKN050 BKN130 10/07 A2994 RMK AO2 SLP140 T01000067,200,2011-01-01 07:54:00
3:54 AM,51.1,44.1,77,29.93,10.0,SSE,5.8,-,N/A,,Scattered Clouds,METAR KBUF 010854Z 15005KT 10SM SCT050 SCT130 11/07 A2992 RMK AO2 SLP134 T01060067 58000,150,2011-01-01 08:54:00
```

Any solution to this would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The link you provided does not give me METAR in Firefox -- maybe you're not using the link you think you are?

Comment: @jjlin: It gives `METAR` in chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Browsing the wunderunderground](http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/KBUF/2012/2/8/DailyHistory.html?req_city=Buffalo%20Niagara%20International&req_state=NY&req_statename=New%20York), I found the ["Show full METARS"](http://www.wunderground.com/cgi-bin/findweather/getForecast?setpref=SHOWMETAR&value=1) link. After clicking there, pointing the browser at the [link you posted](http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/KBUF/2011/1/1/DailyHistory.html?theprefset=SHOWMETAR&theprefvalue=1&format=1) or the ["Comma Delimited File" link](http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/KBUF/2012/2/8/DailyHistory.html?req_city=Buffalo+Niagara+International&req_state=NY&req_statename=New+York&format=1) shows METAR data. It seems to set some cookies. For example, `page.info()` shows that "Prefs" includes "SHOWMETAR:1":

```
Set-Cookie: Prefs=FAVS:1|WXSN:1|PWSOBS:1|WPHO:1|PHOT:1|RADC:0|RADALL:0|HIST0:NULL|GIFT:1|SHOWMETAR:1|PHOTOTHUMBS:50|HISTICAO:KBUF*NULL|; path=/; expires=Fri, 01-Jan-2020 00:00:00 GMT; domain=.wunderground.com
```

---

```
import urllib2
import cookielib

cookieJar = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookieJar))

setmetar = 'http://www.wunderground.com/cgi-bin/findweather/getForecast?setpref=SHOWMETAR&value=1'
request = urllib2.Request(setmetar)
response = opener.open(request)

url = "http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/KBUF/2011/1/1/DailyHistory.html?theprefset=SHOWMETAR&theprefvalue=1&format=1"
request = urllib2.Request(url)
page = opener.open(request)
# print(page.info())
dailyData = page.read()                            
print dailyData
```

yields

```
TimeEST,TemperatureF,Dew PointF,Humidity,Sea Level PressureIn,VisibilityMPH,Wind Direction,Wind SpeedMPH,Gust SpeedMPH,PrecipitationIn,Events,Conditions,FullMetar,WindDirDegrees,DateUTC<br />
12:54 AM,52.0,45.0,77,29.93,10.0,SSW,15.0,-,N/A,,Scattered Clouds,METAR KBUF 010554Z COR 20013KT 10SM FEW045 SCT140 11/07 A2992 RMK AO2 SLP134 60004 T01110072 10111 20078 58016,200,2011-01-01 05:54:00<br />
1:54 AM,53.1,45.0,74,29.95,10.0,SSW,12.7,-,N/A,,Mostly Cloudy,METAR KBUF 010654Z 20011KT 10SM BKN055 BKN130 12/07 A2994 RMK AO2 SLP141 T01170072,200,2011-01-01 06:54:00<br />
```

Answer (score 0):

When I hit that URL through a browser, the data I see is the same as the first sample you include.  Poking around the Wunderground site, it looks like there's a way to register for a developer/API account--if you've done that, and are signed in when retrieving the data, then the discrepancy is likely due to the additional information available to registered users.

If you need to authenticate to get the full data, it'll be worth your time to look into using [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) to help you manage cookies.

Otherwise, I suspect there's a difference in the URLs you're using--the expanded data is probably specified with additional arguments.

Comment: Thanks, the answer is cookie, as the other answer pointed out.